# How could I know where to begin a proof a priori?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am reading "Mathematical Thinking: Problem-Solving and Proofs" by D'Angelo and West.

On chapter 1, inside the "Elementary Inequalities" section, we have proposition 1.3 "Triangle Inequality".

I can follow perfectly and I  understand the justification behind each step. But there is something that is irking/puzzling me...The proof begins with:

"We start off with the inequality $2xy \le 2 |x| |y| $ "

If I had attempted beforehand to prove the proposition on my own, how could I have known this and that that inequality had some relationship with this proposition?

Where does this come from? (There is no previous text showing this inequality)

I assume the author is not...well, the author of this proof. Yet whoever came up with this proof in the first place had to see some sort of connection. Otherwise, we would be beginning proofs with a random initial step, right?

Comment: As a side comment (I dont wanted to make the original post too large)...come think of it, I have come across this in many other math books. Particularly  discrete mathematics books. The author explains a topic and then gives a set of exercises which can be solved with the tools granted by the previous explanation. But the examples given in the explanation also have this "void" where we just start using something out of the blue with no prior explanation of how one could have arrived at it. Is this how it is supposed to be?

Comment: "We start off" does not mean that we would start with this solving a problem. Only much later, when the problem is solved, one sorts out the important steps and then writes "We start off with $2xy$". Nevertheless, it is true that $2xy\le 2|x||y|$ is *indeed* helpful for proving the proposition. But how could you have known this beforehand? Only by trying yourself and not reading the solution.

Comment: @RobertZ You were right. Thanks for the correction.
Dietrich: I understand now what you are saying. However (perhaps I was not clear or confusing)...how could I have imagined that I *should* start off with that inequality? Do I make sense? Why not any other inequality? Just try random inequalities until I come across something that resembles what I am looking for?

Comment: @CyclotomicField True true..I can see that. So one could say that if the proposition has something that resembles another definition, we should start looking into that?

Side comment: Are comments being deleted or something like that? There two other comments apart from Dietrich's one...

Comment: Only after trying many useless inequalities *yourself* you are able to understand why to start with a useful one - and which one this might be. You need practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, what one writes as a formal proof is not the same way the person thought of it. Because usually, the way we "think" of the problem is usually in the opposite direction of the logic of the proof. Let me try to illustrate with an example.

Suppose we want to prove that for every $a,b \geq 0$, we have $\sqrt{ab} \leq \dfrac{a + b}{2}$ (the AGM inequality). I remember exactly how I proved this statement the very first time I saw it. What I did was something very bad logically: I started by assuming the conclusion, but from an intuitive standpoint, if you have absolutely no clue whatsoever, then this approach could be somewhat helpful, because it atleast gives you something to work with.

So, I started by squaring both sides, $ab \leq \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{a^2+2ab + b^2}{4}$. Then, multiply by $4$ to get $4ab \leq a^2 + 2ab + b^2$. Or rearranging, $0\leq a^2-2ab + b^2 = (a-b)^2$, and this last statement is certainly true. Of course, logically whatever I have done amounts to nonsense because I haven't done/proven anything directly addressing the proposition.

But, by doing this preliminary work, you now atleast have an idea of what to try, and where to start from; the goal is to try to "undo" each step (in this very simple case, it turns out to be possible). So, if I were to write a formal proof, it would be something like:

> Suppose $a,b \geq 0$. We start with the inequality $0 \leq (a-b)^2$, which is always true. Next, we expand it out to get $0\leq a^2-2ab+b^2$. Now, we add $4ab$ to both sides, to get $4ab \leq a^2 + 2ab + b^2$. Now, divide by $4$, and factor the numerator of the RHS to get $ab \leq \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$.
>
> Now, in this final stage, because $a\geq 0$ and $b\geq 0$ by hypothesis, the product $ab \geq 0$ as well. Hence, we can "take square roots" on both sides to get $\sqrt{ab} \leq \frac{a+b}{2}$.

And of course, if this is the very first time seeing it, then you might be surprised/questioning how did I even think to start with $0\leq (a-b)^2$. Well, the answer is I didn't get it out of thin air; it was an **educated guess** based on my "scratch work". But as you learn and read more, you usually pick up more and more tricks/ideas/techniques, so that if you encounter a completely new problem, you'll have a larger number of "educated guesses" to make. If one doesn't pan out, try another one. It's really a matter of practice.

---

As for your actual inequality $2xy \leq 2 |x||y|$, I'm not sure the context of the problem, but it's very easy to see that for any $a\in \Bbb{R}$, we have $a\leq |a|$ (it's a simple two-case verification). Now, just plug in $a=2xy$. Then, we have $2xy \leq |2xy|=2 |x||y|$.

Comment: What a coincidence! The next proof in the book was the AGM Inequality! And it was exactly like this one! Now I see how it goes...thanks for having taken the time to write ths.