# Understanding the Proof of Cauchy Inequality (Nicholson Textbook)

Tags: linear-algebra

I looked at similar posts regarding the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, but my 'textbook' does things a little differently.

Here is the Proof:

The inequality holds if $\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ or $\vec{y}=\vec{0}$ (in fact it is equality).
Otherwise, write $\|\vec{x}\|=a \gt 0$ and $\|\vec{y}\|=b \gt 0$ for convenience. With computation, we have:

$\|b\vec{x}-a\vec{y}\|^2=2ab(ab-\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y})$ and $\|b\vec{x}+a\vec{y}\|^2=2ab(ab+\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y})$

It follows that $ab-\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} \ge 0$ and $ab+\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} \ge 0$, and hence that $-ab \le \vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} \le ab$. Hence $|\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}| \le ab=\|\vec{x}\| \|\vec{y}\|$, proving the Cauchy inequality.

This proof follows from Nicholson's Linear Algebra with Applications (Open Edition) textbook.

My question is: Why did we start with letting $\|\vec{x}\|=a \gt 0$ and $\|\vec{y}\|=b \gt 0$, and starting off the proof with $\|b\vec{x}-a\vec{y}\|^2$?

Comment: Because it works

Comment: @tomasliam But why do we start with it?

Comment: It seems like an odd question. We start there because doing so gets the answer. Or are you asking "how did someone think of it?"

Comment: @tomasliam Yeah, how did they come up with it?

Comment: Probably intuition. Someone probably expected the answer, had an excellent insight of the topic, and did a lot of fiddling around with it. I normally prove Cauchy-Schwarz by starting with $\|x-\alpha y\|^2 \ge 0$ and choosing the correct $\alpha$. Which is somewhat similar. When you know the desired result, and have a good understanding of inner-products and norms, its a reasonably intuitive step to take.  Knowing one proof often leads to another, and people normally use the one they like the most.

Comment: The first proofs of results are often clunky and not very general. And over time they get fine tuned and given in a more general setting. Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities existed in one form or another long before the notion of an inner-product space was defined. It was probably originally many pages long. Over time, with better insight and better notation, things are fine tuned and a 5 page proof becomes a 5 line proof.

Comment: As a comment, the one with the $+$ sign, the geometric intuition could be that $b\vec{x}+a\vec{y}$ represents the bisector of $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to start off with the orthogonal decomposition of $y$ along $x$ (or the other way around). Then you're dealing with a right triangle:
$$
                   y=\alpha x + (y-\alpha x)
$$
This is an orthogonal decomposition iff $0=\langle x,y-\alpha x\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle-\alpha\|x\|^2$, or $\alpha = \frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|x\|^2}$. Then
$$
          \|y\|^2=|\alpha|^2\|x\|^2+\|y-\alpha x\|^2=\frac{|\langle x,y\rangle|^2}{\|x\|^4}\|x\|^2+\|y-\alpha x\|^2.
$$
Now it becomes readily apparent that
$$
             \frac{|\langle x,y\rangle|^2}{\|x\|^2} \le \|y\|^2,
$$
and equality holds iff $y=\alpha x$, where $\alpha=\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|x\|^2}$.

If you look at the author's proof, you'll see how the two relate. The author has combined the cases in order to avoid the special cases where something is $0$. That is what introduces the obscurity in the proof. I think it is far preferable to look at the original ideas, and to deal directly with the special cases as special cases. I appreciate the compactness of the author's ideas in eliminating special cases; but sometimes clever is no good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really consider this a full answer, but this is also too long to fit in the comments, hence I post it as an answer. I can't speak for how the author came up with that proof, but I can give you my perspective on it (note that this proof approach only works for real inner product spaces, and we need a different approach in the complex case.).

Note that the inequality $|\langle x,y\rangle|\leq\lVert x\rVert \lVert y\rVert$ is "bilinear homogeneous" on both sides in the sense that if you replace $(x,y)\to (\lambda x, \mu y)$ with non-zero $\lambda,\mu$, then the inequality still holds true. So, the point of introducing $a,b$ as in the proof is really an attempt to exploit this fact in order to make the right factors appear in the right places. The way I would have presented it is that as you mentioned, the inequality is actually an equality if $x=0$ or $y=0$, so the only case is if $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$. In this case, we can divide these vectors by their norm, so that it suffices to prove $|\langle x,y\rangle| \leq 1$ if $x,y$ have norm $1$.

Now, from here, I can't really justify why/how someone might have originally come up with the idea of considering the inequalities $0\leq \langle x+y, x+y\rangle$ and $0 \leq \langle x-y,x-y\rangle$ and then rearranging to get the desired outcome. All I can say is that there are just some things you try and you learn from experience some things which work and some which don't, but one thing is for sure: when in doubt, you want to try to invoke (or imitate the proofs of) things you already know to be true.

Comment: I addressed a similar question in [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3785503/568204) of mine; maybe you'll find the comments useful.